# Optimizing TensorFlow Image Generation for CNN Training with xarray Data

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, python-xarray, satellite-image

I am working on training a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) with satellite imagery data to estimate population density from RGB images. The satellite imagery is stored in a TIFF file, and I am using xarray to open the data. I am facing challenges in efficiently generating datasets for training.

I want to create different images for each training epoch by sampling random images from each section of the xarray.
Currently, I have a function that generates a random point from each polygon in the dataset and creates an image. However, using tf.py_function for this function has resulted in a bottleneck during image generation, as the GPU is constantly waiting for the data to be generated. I think the data is not being prefetched because of the usage of tf.py_function.

This is a minimal version of the code I'm currently working with:

```
import xarray as xr
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from Shapely import Point

img_size = 128
dataset = xr.open_dataset("sat_img.tif")
gdf = gpd.read_file("neighbours.parquet")

def find_nearest_idx(array, value):
    ''' Returns the index of the nearest value of {value} from the array'''
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return idx

def random_point_from_geometry(polygon, size=100):
    '''Generates a random point within the bounds of a Polygon.'''

    # Get bounds of the shapefile's polygon
    (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) = polygon.bounds

    # Loop until finding a random point inside the polygon
    while 0 == 0:
        # generate random data within the bounds
        x = np.random.uniform(minx, maxx, 1)
        y = np.random.uniform(miny, maxy, 1)
        point = Point(x, y)
        if polygon.contains(point):
            return x, y
 
def get_data(i):
    ''' Generates image and label for the neighbour i from the GeoDataFrame. '''
    # Get the polygon and the label of that index (neighbour)
    polygon = gdf.iloc[i]["geometry"]
    label = gdf.iloc[i]["label"]
     
    # Sample point from the polygon's box
    x, y = random_point_from_geometry(
        polygon
    )
    
    # Find the rearest raster of this random point
    idx_x = find_nearest_idx(dataset.x, x)
    idx_y = find_nearest_idx(dataset.y, y)
    
    # Create the indexes of the box of the image
    idx_x_min = round(idx_x - img_size / 2)
    idx_x_max = round(idx_x + img_size / 2)
    idx_y_min = round(idx_y - img_size / 2)
    idx_y_max = round(idx_y + img_size / 2)
    
    image_ds = dataset.isel(
        x=slice(idx_x_min, idx_x_max),
        y=slice(idx_y_min, idx_y_max)
    )
    image_da = image_ds.band_data
    image = image.to_numpy()
    
    return image, label

## The tensorflow section, based on: 
#   https://medium.com/@acordier/tf-data-dataset-generators-with-parallelization-the-easy-way-b5c5f7d2a18
# Generator for the index
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: list(range(df.shape[0])),  # The index generator,
    tf.uint8,
)  # Creates a dataset with only the indexes (0, 1, 2, 3, etc.)

dataset = dataset.map(
    lambda i: tf.py_function(  # The actual data generator. Passes the index to the function that will process the data.
        func=get_data, inp=[i], Tout=[tf.uint8, tf.float32]
    ),
    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE,
)

...
```

Any sugestions on how can I make this process more efficient with tf.function or any other methods? Currently the GPU is most of the time waiting for the images to be generated...

Comment: `find_nearest_idx()` looks suspicious - it's using an O(N) algorithm where a O(log N) or O(1) one would do. [np.searchsorted()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) can be used to find the index where an element would be inserted, assuming an array is sorted in advance. Or, if assuming the indicies are evenly spaced, you could probably do this by dividing by the distance between indicies.

Comment: It's worth noting that `gdf.iloc[i]` is one of the slower ways to iterate over a dataframe. Unsure how much that matters in this case. More information: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06

Comment: Could you try benchmarking it? There are many places you could optimize, but I'm unsure which of them matter. I would suggest doing this by removing the calls to tensorflow, and running your `get_data(i)` in a loop, and using [py-spy](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy) to identify the most expensive parts.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've already replaced the `find_nearest_idx()` for `np.searchsorted()` and bechame much faster than before. After profiling in with py-spy, 87% of the time is spent in reading the tif file after the xarray filtering (I've ommited that part in the previous code). The training runs smoother but still have some bottleneck in the data generation process...